# How to control multiple ESP-01 with an app?

Tags: esp8266

I've been working on a school project that consists into making a smart light socket. I want to make an app which will allow the user to control many of them, like switching on and off, controlling the light intensity and other functions.

So, I guess the most important for me now is to know if I can connect each ESP-01 to the Internet and control them individually.

Comment: As it stands this is very broad. In order to be a question that helps expand the body of knowledge on this site it would be great if you could add some more details to the question. That way it could be answered afterwards in a clearer fashion.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has many topics to take into consideration.  Using an ESP-01 to control a mains powered device from a mobile app via the internet has a lot of pieces to integrate into one project.  It can be done, but if you are asking this question, it may be a bit daunting if your experience is limited.

If you are just getting started, you might consider looking into existing projects like [zigbee2mqtt](https://www.zigbee2mqtt.io) and commercially available smart home lighting [like that from IKEA](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/tradfri-led-bulb-e26-600-lumen-wireless-dimmable-color-and-white-spectrum-opal-20411562/) instead of starting from scratch.  It will get you to your end result a lot faster and you'll have more support in getting it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the informations! I've forgotten to mention that this is intended to be a school project and not something for personal use. I understand it is a very dense topic and I don't know if I'll get to learn it in time.